# Send URL with wp_remote_post not working

Tags: wordpress

I am using a service that accepts URL in this format...

```
http://www.mydomain.com/zone1/code/verify/?data1=Apple&data1=Banana&data3=Orange&data4=Pear
```

I am trying to use wp_remote_post to submit it and receive a response....

```
    $url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/zone1/code/verify/';
    $fields = array();
    $fields['data1'] = 'Apple';
    $fields['data2'] = 'Banana';
    $fields['data3'] = 'Orange';
    $fields['data4'] = 'Pear';

    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'timeout' => 45,
    'redirection' => 5,
    'httpversion' => '1.0',
    'blocking' => true,
    'headers' => array(),
    'body' => $fields,
    'cookies' => array()
    )
);
```

This isn't working and the response I am recieving back is that the fields are missing.

Can anyone see anything wrong with my approach and also is there an easy way to echo out exactly the URL it is sending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This url:

```
http://www..../verify/?data1=Apple&data1=Banana&data3=Orange&data4=Pear
```

is in a GET format, not POST so you should check the API docs for that request, but it likely does not support the POST format so you will need to use the GET syntax, like so:

```
$url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/zone1/code/verify/';
$url .= '?data1=Apple';
$url .= '&data2=Banana';
$url .= '&data3=Orange';
$url .= '&data4=Pear';
$args = array(); //the default arguments should be ok unless the API needs something special like authentication headers
$response = wp_remote_get($url, $args);
```

I like to use the [kint-debugger](http://wordpress.org/plugins/kint-debugger/) plugin to dig through output like this, using that you could call `dd($response);` and get a nicely formatted display of the response. Without that plugin, just add this afterwards:

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($repsonse);
die();
```

This should show everything in the response variable.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation,  it all makes sense.  I am going to try and apply now